# How to remove shadow in Material-UI Dialog?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, material-design

I need to remove the background shadow in the Material-UI dialog. But I can't find the way from API. Anyone can help me with that.

[image]

I need to remove this shadow...

```
<div id={"Location_Massage"} style={{ height: "10px !important" }}>
  <Dialog
    className={classes.location_verify_dialog}
    fullScreen={fullScreen}
    open={open}
    style={{
      marginTop: -470,
      marginLeft: 460
    }}
    onClose={handleClose}
    aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
  >
    <DialogContent>
      <DialogContentText
        style={{
          borderRadius: 12,
          height: "10px !important",
          width: 170
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 700 }}>Me Labs</div>
      </DialogContentText>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
      <Button
        style={{ borderRadius: 15, left: -6, top: -15 }}
        onClick={handleClose}
        color="primary"
        variant={"outlined"}
      >
        Cancel
      </Button>
      <Button
        style={{ borderRadius: 15, left: -4, top: -15 }}
        onClick={handleClose}
        color="primary"
        variant={"contained"}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please also add the code in the question?

Comment: I added my cource code

Comment: That works but unfortunately the click away functionality is also removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.
if you need to remove background from dialog just add these props.

```
hideBackdrop={true}
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't think about looking at the `Modal` props.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. Besides, if you get  ```Value must be omitted for boolean attributes  react/jsx-boolean-value``` this error, changing ```hideBackdrop={true}``` to ```hideBackdrop``` will help.

Answer (score 2):

`Dialog` uses `Paper` component under-the-hood and provides a [`PaperProps`](https://mui.com/api/dialog/#:%7E:text=of%20the%20dialog.-,PaperProps,-object) prop to let you override the `Paper` properties including the `elevation` (which sets the `Paper` shadow).

**EDIT**: If you want to remove the `Backdrop` background color, you can use [`hideBackdrop`](https://mui.com/api/modal/#:%7E:text=scroll%20lock%20behavior.-,hideBackdrop,-bool), it's a `Modal` [prop](https://mui.com/api/modal/) which the `Dialog` inherits from. But you should add some kind of border to be able to see the `Dialog` on the white background:

**V5**

```
<Dialog
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  hideBackdrop
  PaperProps={{
    elevation: 0,
    sx: {
      border: "solid 1px gray"
    }
  }}
>
```

**V4**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  paper: {
    border: "solid 1px gray"
  }
);
```

```
<Dialog
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  hideBackdrop
  PaperProps={{
    elevation: 0,
    className: classes.paper
  }}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: It's not working Sir...

Comment: @Zenixo See my updated answer, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options, using which you can hide the background shadow of the `Dialog` component.

### Option 1

You can use the `location_verify_dialog` class and select the `paper` class in the `makeStyles` or `useStyles`.

```
location_verify_dialog: {
  "& .MuiDialog-paper": {
    boxShadow: "none"
  }
},
```

### Option 2

You can assign a new class to the `paper` key in the `classes` object for the `Dialog` component and remove the background shadow.

```
paper: {
  boxShadow: "none"
}
```

Dialog component

```
<Dialog
    className={classes.location_verify_dialog}
    fullScreen={false}
    open={open}
    style={{
      marginTop: -470,
      marginLeft: 460,
      boxShadow: "none"
    }}
    onClose={handleClose}
    aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
    classes={{ paper: classes.paper }} // this is the class prop
  >
```

Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xsfq2?file=/demo.js) link with both of the options.

Comment: It's not working Sir.

Comment: Do you want to remove the background shadow (a little dark area around the dialog modal) or the whole overlay (which is the entire light greyish background) behind the modal, blocking the interaction with entire page? Could you please provide more details?

Comment: I found a solution...Thank you very much for your time.❤️